# Array even and odd indexes sorting and printing its values

Tags: beginner, ruby

I'm looking for a more elegant solutions of this task.

Task:
Given a string, print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as space-separated strings on a single line.

Input Format:
The first line contains an integer (the number of test cases).
Each line of the subsequent lines contain a string.

```
puts "Input a number of test cases"
t = gets.to_i
t.times do
  puts "Input a string please"  
  s = gets.strip
  z = s.split(//)
  b = z.each_with_index.sort_by { |i, x| [x.even? ? 0 : 1, x] }
  b.map { |i, x| print i if x.even? }
  print " "
  b.map { |i, x| print i if x.odd? }
  puts
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good idea to become familiar with all the methods on `Array` and `Enumerable`. It just so happens that `Enumerable` has a method called `partition` that has a purpose of dividing an array into .two parts (e.g. even and odd). It'll help tidy up your code.

So let's use partition on the array of `chars` and partition based on index.

```
parts = s.chars.partition.with_index{|_,i| i.even?}
```

Note since we are only using the index, the actual character is unimportant so I used `_` instead of a variable name in the `partition` block. 
Now you have two arrays of characters--let's join each array so that you have a single array with two strings:

```
strings = parts.map(&:join)
```

If you don't know about `&:join` it is a shortcut for `{|a| a.join}` (using `Symbol#to_proc` if you want to read up on it).

Then, finally print it. Note that in your code, you intermingle printing with manipulation. This is best avoided if you can; print only once you have things in final form.

```
print strings.join(' ')
```

The above could all be put together in one line if you'd rather:

```
print s.chars.partition.with_index{|_,i| i.even?}.map(&:join).join(' ')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was sure there is a magiс one-liner for this thing :).